# MySQL build query with criteria from second table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to build a query that selects data from table feeds, based upon a specific category in the category column.
I have a second table which lists alternative categories which the query should also take into account. I am not sure how to incorporate this in the code below.

For example:
If $category = 'sports' the current query below selects all data where category matches 'sports'.
The second table lists for category 'sports' the alternative categories 'soccer' and 'Bayern Munchen'.
The new query should now select all data where category matches 'sports','soccer' and 'Bayern Munchen'.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM feeds where category like '$category'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $fid1 = $row["id"];
    $feed_id1 = $row["feed_id"];
    $link1 = $row["link"];
    $title1 = $row["title"];
    $output .= '<a href="detail/' . $fid1 . '" title="' . $title1 . '">' . $title1 . '</a><br/>';
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query); 
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will do:

```
CREATE TABLE data (data integer, category varchar(40));
INSERT INTO data (data, category) VALUES (10, "sport");
INSERT INTO data (data, category) VALUES (20, "soccer");
INSERT INTO data (data, category) VALUES (30, "programming");
INSERT INTO data (data, category) VALUES (40, "Bayern Munich");

CREATE TABLE category_lookup (category1 varchar(40), category2 varchar(40));
INSERT INTO category_lookup (category1, category2) VALUES ("sport", "Bayern Munich");
INSERT INTO category_lookup (category1, category2) VALUES ("sport", "soccer");
INSERT INTO category_lookup (category1, category2) VALUES ("programming", "java");
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE category IN (
  SELECT "sport" UNION 
  SELECT category2 FROM category_lookup WHERE category1 LIKE "sport");
```

See SQL-Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a56b73/1/0

If you add an entry in the category_lookup table for a self lookup:

```
 INSERT INTO category_lookup (category1, category2) VALUES ("sport", "sport");
```

Then you can get rid of the UNION in the query of course.

Comment: You made my day luksch.